# Transfer files from terminal in Linux (ubuntu)

Tags: linux, file-transfer

the deal is to transfer some files from my computer to a server located in my university, assuming the server is located in my.server.com.mx and my user name is user123, which commands do I need to transfer my file?

Comment: Do you know what services the server at `my.server.com.mx` is running? Are they running, for example, `ftpd` or `sshd`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scp file1 file2 file3 user123@my.server.com.mx:
```

or if installed :

```
rsync -avP file1 file2 file3 user123@my.server.com.mx:
```

---

if no path is specified after the `:`, the files will reside in the remote `HOME` : `/home/user123`

Comment: This of course depends upon whether the system at `my.server.com.mx` has `sshd` running.